# How to send form data in a POST request in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

I want to send form data with the POST request. I have tried setting up the headers and setting payloads.

```
req.setPayload("text=you are amazing");
req.addHeader("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

It results as,

```
{message:"Entity body is not json compatible since the received content-type is : text/plain", cause:null}
```

When the setStringPayload method is used,

```
req.setStringPayload("text=you are amazing");
req.addHeader("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

an error occurs as follows.

```
error: senuri/sms-sender:1.0.0/sms_sender.bal:72:5: undefined function 'setStringPayload' in struct 'ballerina/http:Request'
```

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and Ballerina 0.975.0

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason for getting below error is the content type is not properly overridden.

> {message:"Entity body is not json compatible since the received
>   content-type is : text/plain", cause:null}

[setPayload](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/http.html#Request-setPayload) method infers the type of payload by the method parameter and set respective default parameter. In this instance, payload is string type, so content-type is set as text/plain. 
[addHeader](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/http.html#Request-addHeader) method doesn't replace existing header values as it just adds another entry for particular existing header name.

Since priority is given to the first enty content-type is still text/plain. Solution is to use [setHeader](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/http.html#Request-setHeader) which replaces the existing header value.

```
req.setPayload("text=you are amazing");
req.setHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Regarding the second query, setStringPaylaod is renamed to [setTextPaylaod](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/http.html#Request-setTextPayload). So using following code, form data can be sent. Overriding content-type is important as default content type for setting payload via setTextPaylaod is text/plain.

```
req.setTextPayload("text=you are amazing");
req.setHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

[getFormParams](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/http.html#Request-getFormParams) method can be used to retrieve param as a map.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of that method.